# Infinispan Warning: org.jgroups.conf.XmlConfigurator: version is missing in the configuration file

Tags: java, wildfly, cluster-computing, infinispan, jgroups

at my company I am currently upgrading from Wildfly 19 to Wildfly 20. As a result I hab to upgrade the version of our Infinispan Cache from 9.x to 10.x. When I start my application I'm now getting multiple lines of warnings that always say:
`WARN  [org.jgroups.conf.XmlConfigurator] (MSC service thread 1-1) version is missing in the configuration file`

My DefaultCacheManager gets initialized like this:
`EmbeddedCacheManager infManager = new DefaultCacheManager(new GlobalConfigurationBuilder().build());` 
So Infinispan would use its default jgroups configuration file.

How can I avoid that warnings? Is there something wrong with the default configuration file? Do I have to provide a custom one, although I'm only using local caches? Or is it a completly different problem?

Thanks in advance for everyone who can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JGroups (which is used for clustering in Infinispan and Wildfy) introduced a version attribute in the configuration files, with release 4.2.2.Final (see https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JGRP-2401).

Infinispan 10/11 still uses JGroups 4.2.1.Final and so the default configuration files shipped don't have the version attribute.

IMO, it is safe to ignore since I don't expect any significant (API) changes between 4.2.1.Final and 4.2.4.Final (for the record, Wildfly 20 is using JGroups 4.2.4.Final).

If you want to remove the warning, you can copy the default configuration files from Infinispan (or create your own) and add the missing version attribute.